# How to determine whether a set of propositions is consistent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Definition of consistency is: A set of formulas ⊆ WFF is consistent iff there is no A ∈ WFF such that Σ ⊢ A and Σ ⊢ (¬A).

Say you have a set of propositions statements (i.e. $A \lor B \rightarrow C$, etc.) and let's call this "Set1".

I know that to prove that set is inconsistent, you find an "A" such that Set1 ⊢ A and Set1 ⊢ (¬A).

But what are the steps to prove that the set is consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful technique for proving $\Sigma$ consistent is to provide a *model* for it -- that is, an interpretation of the primitive symbols in it that makes every formula in $\Sigma$ *true*. If the logic is *sound*, it cannot conclude something false from true, so whenever $\Sigma\vdash A$, then $A$ will also be true *in that model*. Since $A$ and $\neg A$ cannot both be true in the same interpretation, this means that $\Sigma$ is consistent.

If the logic is *complete* then every consistent $\Sigma$ will have a model. Usual propositional logic and first-order logic are both complete.

In the case of propositional logic, an interpretation is simply a table that shows which propositional letters we take to be true and which ones we take to be false. If $\Sigma$ contains finitely many different propositional letters, we can in principle try all interpretations until we find one that is a model.

The situation is less nice for first-order logic. It is still true that every consistent $\Sigma$ *has* a model, but the model may need to contain infinitely many elements for the quantifiers to range over, and is not necessarily easy to describe. Even if we have a description for a model, *proving* that it is actually a model can be very difficult -- in some sense it can be exactly as difficult as proving the $\Sigma$ is consistent.

And due to Gödel's incompleteness theorems, we know that are first-order theories that *are* consistent but *cannot be proved to be consistent* (from any given meta-system we wish to conduct this proof in).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with *propositional logic* (I assume it from the text of your answer) and $Set_1$ is a *finite* set of formulas (like your : $A \lor B \rightarrow C$), you can use the [Method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) :

> the *semantic tableau* (or *truth tree*) is it is a decision procedure for sentential and related logics.

In case $Set_1$ is *consistent*, it gives you a model of it (because $Set_1$ is *consistent* iff it is *satisfiable*).